# Marklogic installation interrupts with JDK 18 installation

Tags: docker, marklogic

I am trying to install MarkLogic 10 and then deploy some files in the MarkLogic server using MLCP in a CentOS machine using a docker image.
I have installed the following in the CentOS machine using a docker image -

```
MarkLogic 10-.0-9.4x86_64.rpm,
mlcp-10.0.9 and
jdk-18.0.2.1_linux-x64_bin.rpm
```

When I run the container, MarkLogic installs,starts and prompts to set up the admin server on localhost.
But just after the jdk installation, the admin server automatically shuts down and hence the mlcp does not find any running host to import the file.

Is there any dependency/compatibility issue with the JDK version which I have used ?

Comment: Any logs or error messages that you can post?

Comment: INFO contentpump.FileAndDirectoryInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.ServerResponseException: Unrecognized response code (403). Is this an XDBC server?
 at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.handlers.UnrecognizedCodeHandler.handleResponse(UnrecognizedCodeHandler.java:30) ~[marklogic-xcc-10.0.9.jar:?]
 at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.SessionImpl.submitRequestInternal(SessionImpl.java:495) ~[marklogic-xcc-10.0.9.jar:?]
WARN mapreduce.MarkLogicOutputFormat: Unable to connect to localhost to query destination information

Comment: Is there an option to attach the log files here? As I am not able to paste the entire log due to word limitation.

Comment: Just adding that, if I run an image just to install the MarkLogic it works fine. But when I am installing java and then trying to use the mlcp the installed MarkLogic server shuts down. Not sure if it is any interruption with the ports I am using. I have initialized 8000 to 8002 to use.

Comment: MLCP may have issues with Java 18. I know there are issues reported with Java 11 (that will be addressed soon in the MLCP 11 release), but if it's saying Unable to connect to localhost, wondering if there are availability issues with the MarkLogic Server. Is there anything interesting reported in the ErrorLog.txt?

Comment: Actually, I have found out another issue meanwhile. The java set up is not successful. I am using jdk19 and have also used jdk 18. And it shows this in my container log. As I am using a docker image on a centos7 running in windows machine, so I cannot see the java home path. Maybe that needs to be corrected.

Comment: I am using the below commands in my docker file

Comment: wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "https://download.oracle.com/java/19/latest/jdk-19_linux-x64_bin.rpm" -O /tmp/jdk-19_linux-x64_bin.rpm
echo -e "Downloaded jdk \n"
chmod a+x /tmp/jdk-19_linux-x64_bin.rpm
yum -y install /tmp/jdk-19_linux-x64_bin.rpm
JAVA_HOME="/tmp/java/jdk-19_linux-x64_bin.rpm"
MLCP_VERSION="10.0.9"
echo -e "Installed jdk succesfully \n"